# Un modal agarra y muestra datos que no son debido a un onclick

Tags: javascript

Encontré este error extraño en mi código de modal que funciona mediante una tabla

Al presionar un botón de las alertas, éste botón debe mostrar los datos de la alerta de esa persona en un modal, el problema es que parece que el código se está agarrando los datos de las primeras alertas que se generan (Es decir, las alertas de la fila de arriba); los datos de la alerta si están dentro de los botones, pero el modal se agarra los datos de la primera fila de la tabla

Éste es el código que genera la tabla, todo funciona bien. El problema ocurre en los botones de mostraralertapersonal, mostraralertafisica, mostraralertasalud

EDICIÓN: Nada mas puse el codigo que muestra las alertas

```
 function cargarTablaParticipantes(){
            var Id_clase = $("#Id_clase").val();
            var fechaClase = document.getElementById('fechaClase').value;
            datos = {
                "opcion"  : "clientesClase",
                "Id_clase":Id_clase
            };

            $.ajax({
                url:'../controllers/clasesController.php',
                type:'POST',
                data: datos
            }).done(function(response){

                var data = JSON.parse(response).respuesta;
                var msj = JSON.parse(response).msj;
                var success = JSON.parse(response).success; 

                html=`
                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td><strong>Alertas y Patologías</strong></td>
                            <td><strong>Nombre cliente</strong></td>
                            <td><strong>Cédula</strong></td>
                            <td><strong>Teléfono</strong></td>
                            <td><strong>Paquete</strong></td>
                            <td><strong>Fecha de vencimiento</strong></td>
                            <td><strong>Clases Restantes</strong></td>
                            <td><strong>Web</strong></td>
                            <td><strong>Asistió</strong></td>
                            <td><strong>Estado</strong></td>
                            <td><strong>Acción</strong></td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>`;

                if(success){
                    var valores = eval(data);
                    datos = JSON.stringify(valores);
                    console.log(valores);
                    for(i=0;i<valores.length;i++){

                       //var alerta1 = valores[i]["alerta_fisica"];
                       //var alerta2 = valores[i]["alerta_personal"];

                        //if(alerta1 == "") {
                        //
                        //} else if (alerta2 == "") {
                        // 
                        //}else if (alerta1 == "" AND alerta2 == ""){
                        //
                        //}else{
                         //   
                        //}

                        html+=`<tr>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            id="Lista_espera"
                            name="Lista_espera"
                            value="${valores[i]["lista_espera"]}"
                            hidden
                        />
                        <input 
                            type="text"
                            class="form-control"
                            id="Id${valores[i]["id_usuario"]}"
                            name="Id"
                            value= "${valores[i]["id_usuario"]}" 
                            hidden
                        />
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            id="Id_paquetecliente${valores[i]["id_usuario"]}"
                            name="Id_paquetecliente"
                            value="${valores[i]["id_paquetecliente"]}"
                            hidden
                        />
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            id="Lista${valores[i]["id_usuario"]}"
                            name="Lista"
                            value="${valores[i]["lista_espera"]}"
                            hidden
                        />
                        `;

                        //No hay alerta personal ni salud, pero si fisica
                        if(valores[i]["alerta_personal"] == '' && valores[i]["alerta_salud"] == null && valores[i]["alerta_fisica"] !== ''){
                            console.log("Solo alerta Fisica");
                            html+=`
                            <td><i id="iconoalerta2" title="Alerta Administrativa" data-toggle='modal' data-target='#ver_clase'
                            class='fas fa-exclamation-triangle' onclick='mostraralertafisica(${datos});' style='color:green; cursor:pointer;' 
                            value="${valores[i]["alerta_fisica"]}"></i>
                            </td>`;

                        //No hay alerta fisica, ni personal pero si salud
                        }else if(valores[i]["alerta_fisica"] == '' && valores[i]["alerta_personal"] == '' && valores[i]["alerta_salud"] !== null){
                         console.log("Solo Patología");
                         html+=`
                            <td><i id="iconoalerta3" title="Patología" data-toggle='modal' data-target='#ver_clase'
                            class='fas fa-file-medical' onclick='mostraralertasalud(${datos});' style='color:red; cursor:pointer;' 
                            value="${valores[i]["alerta_fisica"]}"></i>
                            </td>`;

                        //No hay alerta fisica, ni salud pero si personal
                        }else if(valores[i]["alerta_fisica"] == '' && valores[i]["alerta_salud"] == null && valores[i]["alerta_personal"] !== ''){
                            console.log("Solo alerta Personal");
                            html+=`
                            <td><i id="iconoalerta1" title="Alerta Personal" data-toggle='modal' data-target='#ver_clase'
                            onclick='mostraralertapersonal(${datos});'
                            class="fas fa-exclamation-circle" style="color:yellow; cursor:pointer;" 
                            value="${valores[i]["alerta_personal"]}"></i></td></td>`;

                        //No hay alertas de ningun tipo
                        }else if(valores[i]["alerta_fisica"] == '' && valores[i]["alerta_personal"] == '' && valores[i]["alerta_salud"] == null){
                            console.log("No hay alertas");
                            html+=`
                            <td>No hay alertas</td>`;

                        //Alerta de salud mas personal
                        }else if(valores[i]["alerta_fisica"] == '' && valores[i]["alerta_personal"] !== '' && valores[i]["alerta_salud"] !== null){
                            console.log("Salud mas personal");
                            html+=`
                            <td>
                            <i id="iconoalerta1" title="Alerta Personal" data-toggle='modal' data-target='#ver_clase'
                            onclick='mostraralertapersonal(${datos});'
                            class="fas fa-exclamation-circle" style="color:yellow; cursor:pointer;" 
                            value="${valores[i]["alerta_personal"]}"></i>
                            <i id="iconoalerta3" title="Patología" data-toggle='modal' data-target='#ver_clase' 
                            class='fas fa-file-medical' onclick='mostraralertasalud(${datos});' style="color:red; cursor:pointer;" 
                            value="${valores[i]["alerta_salud"]}"></i></td>`;  

                        //Alerta de salud mas fisica
                        }else if(valores[i]["alerta_fisica"] !== '' && valores[i]["alerta_personal"] == '' && valores[i]["alerta_salud"] !== null){
                            console.log("Salud mas fisica");
                            html+=`
                            <td>
                            <i id="iconoalerta2" title="Alerta Administrativa" data-toggle='modal' data-target='#ver_clase'
                            class='fas fa-exclamation-triangle' onclick='mostraralertafisica(${datos});' style='color:green; cursor:pointer;' 
                            value="${valores[i]["alerta_fisica"]}"></i>
                            <i id="iconoalerta3" title="Patología" data-toggle='modal' data-target='#ver_clase' 
                            class='fas fa-file-medical' onclick='mostraralertasalud(${datos});' style="color:red; cursor:pointer;" 
                            value="${valores[i]["alerta_salud"]}"></i>
                            </td>`;  

                        //Alerta personal mas fisica
                        }else if(valores[i]["alerta_fisica"] !== '' && valores[i]["alerta_personal"] !== '' && valores[i]["alerta_salud"] == null){
                            console.log("Personal mas fisica");
                            html+=`
                            <td><i id="iconoalerta1" title="Alerta Personal" data-toggle='modal' data-target='#ver_clase'
                                onclick='mostraralertapersonal(${datos});'
                                class="fas fa-exclamation-circle" style="color:yellow; cursor:pointer;" 
                                value="${valores[i]["alerta_personal"]}"></i>
                                <i id="iconoalerta2" title="Alerta Administrativa" data-toggle='modal' data-target='#ver_clase'
                                class='fas fa-exclamation-triangle' onclick='mostraralertafisica(${datos});' style='color:green; cursor:pointer;' 
                                value="${valores[i]["alerta_fisica"]}"></i></td>`; 

                        //Todas las alertas
                        }else{
                        console.log("Todas las alertas");
                        html+=`
                        <td><i id="iconoalerta1" title="Alerta Personal" data-toggle='modal' data-target='#ver_clase'
                        onclick='mostraralertapersonal(${datos});'
                        class="fas fa-exclamation-circle" style="color:yellow; cursor:pointer;" 
                        value="${valores[i]["alerta_personal"]}"></i>
                        <i id="iconoalerta2" title="Alerta Administrativa" data-toggle='modal' data-target='#ver_clase'
                        class='fas fa-exclamation-triangle' onclick='mostraralertafisica(${datos});' style='color:green; cursor:pointer;' 
                        value="${valores[i]["alerta_fisica"]}"></i>
                        <i id="iconoalerta3" title="Patología" data-toggle='modal' data-target='#ver_clase' 
                        class='fas fa-file-medical' onclick='mostraralertasalud(${datos});' style="color:red; cursor:pointer;" 
                        value="${valores[i]["alerta_salud"]}"></i></td></td>`;
                        }

                        html+=`
                        <td><a 
                        href='profile.php?id=${valores[i]["id_usuario"]}' target="_blank"
                        >${valores[i]["primer_nombre"]} ${valores[i]["primer_apellido"]}</a></td>
                        <td>${numeral(valores[i]["cedula"]).format('0,0')}</td>
                        <td>${valores[i]["movil"]}</td>
                        <td>${valores[i]["nombre_paquete"] || 'Clase Gratis'}</td>
                        <td>${moment(valores[i]["fecha_vencimiento"] || fechaClase,'YYYY-MM/DD').format('DD/MM/YYYY')}</td>
                        <td>${valores[i]["cantidad_clases"] || 0}</td>
                        <td>${valores[i]["web"]}</td>`;
                        if(valores[i]["asistio"] == 'Si'){
        }
```

Estos son los codigo de las funciones que explique

```
    //Mostrar el modal de la alerta
    function mostraralertapersonal(datos){
        console.log("Ran");
        datos = datos[0];
        console.log(datos);
       
        document.getElementById("titulo").innerHTML = "Alerta Personal";
        document.getElementById("descripcion_clase").innerHTML = datos['alerta_personal'];
    }

    function mostraralertafisica(datos){
        console.log("Ran");
        datos = datos[0];
        console.log(datos);
       
        document.getElementById("titulo").innerHTML = "Alerta Administrativa";
        document.getElementById("descripcion_clase").innerHTML = datos['alerta_fisica'];
    }

    function mostraralertasalud(datos){
        console.log("Ran");
        datos = datos[0];
        console.log(datos);
       
        document.getElementById("titulo").innerHTML = "Patología";
        document.getElementById("descripcion_clase").innerHTML = datos['alerta_salud'];
    }
```

Este es el modal

```
<style>
    textarea{
        border: 0px none; 
    }
</style>
<center>
<div class="modal fade" id="ver_clase">  
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content" style="height:50%; width: 80%;">
            <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:purple;">
                <div id="titulo" style="color: white;"></div>
                <button 
                type="button" 
                class="close" 
                data-dismiss="modal" 
                aria-label="Close" 
                id="close" 
                name="close"
                style="color: white; opacity: 1;">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <textarea class="autoheight" readonly style="width:100%; height:100%;" id="descripcion_clase"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</center>
```

Para que vean el problema, en inspecionar el onclick está corriendo la primera fila porque es lo primero que ve, el value de alerta salud en la segunda fila (Donde hice inspeccionar elemento) como pueden ver es "Hola" mientras que el value de la alerta de la primera fila es NULL es decir no tiene
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Está bien intentar poner todos los detalles en una pregunta, pero lo que necesitamos es todos los detalles **relacionados** con el problema. Hay demasiado código ahí y cuesta seguirlo. Te recomiendo intentar que la función que le pasas a `done` fuera mucho más pequeña, dividiendo ese trabajo entre varias funciones a las que llamas desde la principal.

Comment: Reducire el codigo hasta solo las alertas, para que puedan verlo mejor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás definiendo la variable `datos` en un contexto no limitado y, además, nunca cambia:

```
datos = JSON.stringify(valores);
for(i = 0; i < valores.length; i++) {
     // Agregar evento a botón
     boton.addEventListener('click', () => hacerAlgo(datos));
}
```

Es lógico que todos los botones tengan el mismo contenido. Debes actualizar la variable en cada iteración del ciclo y, además, asegurarte de que esa variable esté disponible solo dentro del ciclo, definiéndola con `let` (incluyendo el índice para recorrer los valores):

```
for(let i=0; i < valores.length; i++) {
     // Definir variable interna, suponemos que va a estar basada en valores
     let datos = JSON.stringify(valores[i]);
     // Agregar evento a botón
     boton.addEventListener('click', () => hacerAlgo(datos));
}
```

Finalmente, tienes mucho código que se repite para cada alerta, seguramente se puede simplificar creando algunas variables para cambiar tipo de alerta, función que debe ejecutar, clase, etc.